# What is the use of MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h in iOS

Tags: ios, core-services

I have added mobile core services framework many times in my applications but i don't know what is the actual use of this framework.

From apple site i fond only one line explanation:

**-------Mobile Core Services Framework-----
The Mobile Core Services framework (MobileCoreServices.framework) defines the low-level types used in uniform type identifiers (UTIs).
For more information about the types defined by this framework, see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference.**

So i want to know what type of functionality i can achieve by using this framework.

Please send me the Mobile Core Services Framework use-list.

Regards.......

Comment: I have my doubts that the actual off-topic concerns apply here, so I edited the question (to match my real-world problem). As typical, Apple has two generations of documentation, "archived" and what I call "modern", and between the two, there is usually functionality but it remains mysterious to those of us trying to learn it. I see these functions, but don't know what they are used for.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [answer for a question similar to yours](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=14874939&postcount=5):

> The times you need to use UTIs is if you're sharing files between
>   applications. You'll need to use UTIs to open files downloaded from
>   Safari or Mail or transferred to the device through iTunes. You'll
>   also need UTIs if you'd like to send data to another app, like Mail or
>   to transferred to a computer through iTunes.

And, as Apple describes it, [you can use UTI's to describe an entire class of entities with a type (such as the format for files)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/UniformTypeIdentifier.html).